# phpMyAdmin not allowing me to store decimals

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to store currency in a new table I named "Payable" and have a row "amount", which will store that data... I've tried numerous times to make amount decimal(10,2) or Float decimal(10,2) or (8,2) and every time I do phpMyAdmin saves it as 10,0 or 8,0.

Does anyone know how to solve this? My hosting is dreamhost, MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? What exactly have you entered in the "Length/Values" field? I've tried with `10,2`, `10,0`, and `8,0`; each of those work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`table` 
ADD COLUMN `cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL AFTER `column`;

INSERT INTO `test`.`table` (`column1`, `cost`) VALUES ('test', 40.35);

Select * from table;
# id, name, cost
2,  test,            40.35
1,  Xanax (0.5mg),   10.25
```

Comment: I tried your code: ALTER TABLE `amount`.`Payable` ADD COLUMN `cost` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL AFTER `payee` and got the follow:

MySQL said: #1142 - Alter command denied to user 'admin'@id-208-113-156.25.dreamhost.com' for table 'Payable'

Comment: After "chatting" with DreamHost this is what was said: 

DH - "I was looking into this with one of our admins, and unfortunately this would be something beyond the scope of our support"

Me - "So what do I do then?"

DH - "This would be something you would need to look into on your own, or ask someone familiar with this."